# using the ellipsoid algorithm to find a poly time algorithm for the optimization problem

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem: Let $n$ be even and let $c, x$ be positive vectors in
$\mathbb{R}^n.$ Find
$\min(c^Tx)$ for $\sum_S x_i\geq 1,$ for any $S\subset \{1,...,n\}$ with $|S| =n/2$.
We have to show that the ellipsoid algorithm can be used to get a poly(n)-time algorithm for the problem.

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but I can't really see what you mean to say about the sets $S$.

Comment: yeah thanks for the editing.S are just the set of indices

Comment: also S is a subset of [n] not belongs to...[n] represents the set of n linearly independent columns

Comment: Do you mean that whenever I take $n/2$ elements of $x$, they sum to at least $1$?

Comment: yeah...right...xi's are elements of x.So x1,x2...xn/2

Comment: @KevinCarlson ...I also think there is an O(nlogn) algorithm for the problem.But again can't figure out how ...